# How do I encrypt the connection string with EF 4.1 Code First?

Tags: winforms, entity-framework, code-first

I'm using the Code First RC to build a class library and I would like to be able to encrypt the connection string that I'm using.  The consumers of the class library could be ASP.NET or Windows Forms apps, so I need an encryption method that works with both.

It appears that I can pass in a connection string to DbContext by name, but not by value, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4805094/pass-connection-string-to-code-first-dbcontext), so I don't think I can manually decrypt within my program before passing the string to DbContext.  Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily encrypt any .NET configuration section - not just in ASP.NET as many devs seem to think, but absolutely also in other apps.

Check out [Jon Galloway's blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2008/04/13/encrypting-passwords-in-a-net-app-config-file.aspx) on the topic - excellent read!

With this approach, you could encrypt the `<connectionStrings>` section - and to make it easier still, you could externalize that section into a separate file, too.

So in your `app.config` for your Winforms app, you'd have:

```
<connectionStrings configSource="ConnectionStrings.config" />
```

and the same would be in your `web.config` for your web application, and the file referenced would contain just the  `<connectionStrings>` and that could be encrypted. Load the appropriate connection string from your config, and pass it into your `DbContext` constructor, and you should be fine.

Comment: Will encrypting a section work if you are using transformations? ie. `Web.Release.config`?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a full connection string into DbContext:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/01/27/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-2-connections-and-models.aspx

Under "Other DbContext Constructor Options":

> ...
>
> - You can pass a full connection string    to DbContext instead of just
>     the    database or connection string
>     name.    By default this connection
>     string is    used with the
>     System.Data.SqlClient    provider;
>     this can be changed by    setting a
>     different implementation of
>     IConnectionFactory onto
>     context.Database.DefaultConnectionFactory.
> - You can use an existing DbConnection    object by passing it
>     to a DbContext    constructor. If the
>     connection object    is an instance of
>     EntityConnection,    then the model
>     specified in the    connection will be
>     used in    Database/Model First mode.
>     If the    object is an instance of
>     some other    type—for example,
>     SqlConnection—then    the context will
>     use it for Code    First mode.
>
> ...

If this is true, then you can use AES or some other encryption to encrypt the string in the .config file, then decrypt at runtime and feed it into the DbContext constructor.