# Set EF 6 connection string dynamically

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I've seen quite a few posts about this but I don't understand how to implement this.

My connection string is specified as "MealsContext" in app.config, My EF datamodel container name is "MealsContext", how can I use an instance of MealsContext but define the connection string to be used at runtime? If I create a new EntityConnection it doesn't know what entity objects are in the model, e.g. this is what I'm currently doing...

```
    private MealsContext context = new MealsContext();

public void InsertOrUpdate(Meal _entity)
        {
            context.Entry(_entity).State = _entity.Id == default(int) ? EntityState.Added : EntityState.Modified;
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Comment: I think there is an DbContext constructor, which allows you to Input a Connection string.

Comment: look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4805094/pass-connection-string-to-code-first-dbcontext

Comment: I think you need to pass in not the name of the connection string in the config file, but the connection string itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF 6's base class for database contexts,`DbContext`, has a couple of overloads - one of which takes a `DbConnection` and a Boolean flag indicating if the previously mentioned `DbConnection` object should be disposed of when the context is disposed (IOW if true, the `DbConnection` is disposed when the context is disposed). you could also use the constructor overload that simply takes a connection string, but I wanted to throw in an example showing how to do this while controlling the life time of the `DbConnection` object.

the snag is that when your specific context is generated, by default only the default (public/parameterless) constructor is made available, which if you look at the generated class, alludes to using a config file based EF connection string entry. the good thing is that your generated context that inherits from the `DbContext` follows the best practice of generating your context class with the partial modifier, which allows you create your own `partial` implementation of your specific model's context.

I would recommend creating a new class file (explicitly NOT the code generated file) in your project and, at a minimum, make a `partial` implementation of your model's context class with just a constructor that has a `DbConnection` and a `bool` argument to mirror the aforementioned `DbContext` constructor signature.

for example, if the generated context is defined as:

```
public partial class MyModelContainer : DbContext...
```

then you can create your partial class implementation (in your shiny, new, and separate class file of course):

```
public partial class MyModelContainer
{
    public MyModelContainer(DbConnection dbConnection, bool contextOwnsConnection)
        : base(dbConnection, contextOwnsConnection)
    {
        // you can other stuff here if you need to, but don't have to for this example
    }
}
```

if you've gotten this far, you should be able to create `MyModelContainer` objects with database connections as dynamic as the connection strings used by the `DbConnection` object you provide.

example:

```
public void DynamicConnectionExample(string entityConnectionString)
{
    DbConnection dbConnection = new EntityConnection(entityConnectionString);
    bool shouldImplicitlyDisposeOfConnection = true;
    using (var ctx = new MyModelContext(dbConnection, shouldImplicitlyDisposeOfConnection))
    {
        // do stuff...
    }
 }
```

obviously, you could get a little creative with ways to configure the DbConnection object's connection string and I would recommend exploring ways of doing so other than the way shown in the example.

Also worth noting: depending on whether you're using model-first or code-first the would have an impact on the specialized type of `DbConnection` you would be using. for instance, you would use an `EntityConnection` object if you're using an EF model because of the required access to metadata compiled resources in your assembly.

ref: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696604(v=vs.113).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696604%28v=vs.113%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anyone else is looking for this, I cobbled the answer together from a few other posts which say the same thing but I didn't get it at first. I added several different named connection strings in the app.config file. Then I overrode the context class which is in the entity model so that it takes the name of the connection string as a parameter

```
public MealsContext(string connectionString) : base(connectionString)
```

{

}

The string that I passed in is "name=csTest", where csTest is a connection string defined in the app.config. The trick though, is to specify this context somewhere separately - e.g. in a class library folder, so that the context doesn't get overwritten automatically when the model is updated or rebuilt.