# Entity Framework model first connection string

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework model-first. After finishing my site, I did a `Publish`. I am using Entity Framework and a database connection setup using a connection string from settings.config:

```
<add key="thenna" 
     value="server=11.3.34.45;database=montage;user id=sample;password=Test;trusted_connection=false;"/>
```

I have config changed server database details.

My entity framework connection string in `web.config`:

```
<add name="tickandtieEntities" 
     connectionString="metadata=res://*/Entityframework.Tickmarks.csdl|res://*/Entityframework.Tickmarks.ssdl|res://*/Entityframework.Tickmarks.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=DESKTOP-QD6A981\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=tickandtie;user id=sa;password=tickmarks;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
     providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

When I change `web.config` file with server details I get an error

> Cannot open database "tickandtie" requested by the login

How can I configure Entity Framework in `web.config` when I move my app to the host server? Please help me anyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by [setting the connection string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4805094/pass-connection-string-to-code-first-dbcontext) on your EF Db Context at creation time, passing your setting value to your EF context.

E.g.: adding a constructor on your context, which uses the base DbContext constructor to pass the connection string:

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDbContext(string connString) : base(connString)
    {
    }
}
```

Which then make your context used like:

```
var connectionString = "" // Get the value of of your custom config file here.
var ctx = new MyDbContext(connectionString);
```

As stated above, you need to read your connection string value **first** out of your `settings.config` file.

Comment: Please Explain more about it

Comment: thank. I have Sql db connection string  appsettings Folder  and Entity framework  connection string web config  file  ,where i  apply this code ?

Comment: Using the code above means you don't need to use the default EF connection string in Web.config. You can then get it from a specific location (e.g. appSettings) using the [ConfigurationManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager(v=vs.110).aspx). class