# EF Core Connection string is not available in the controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have an ASP.NET Core 7 application with Entity Framework. I created a minimal example that exhibits the problem.

`appsettings.Development.json` (note that the problem doesn't exist if the connection string is in `appsettings.json`):

```
{
    "ConnectionStrings": {
        "DefaultConnection": "Data Source=..."
    }
}
```

`Program.cs`

```
WebApplicationBuilder builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();

string connstr = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")!;
builder.Services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(optionsBuilder =>
    optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connstr));
...
```

`connstr` shows the connection string from `appsettings.Development.json` as expected.

Controller

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class CountriesController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly MyContext _db;

    public CountriesController(MyContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Country>>> Get()
    {
        List<Country> countries = await _db.Countries.ToListAsync();
        return countries;
    }
    ...
}
```

And when I invoke this `Get()` method I get an error:

> The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.

I can't understand how it got lost from `Program.cs` to the controller?

Comment: can you post your `MyContext` class?

Comment: @BagusTesa - sure! Any particular method? It is in a separate project, and it's a pretty large file. Please advise which part you think might be relevant to this question. Thanks

Comment: double check that you are not overriding the `ConnectionString` somewhere in the `MyContext` class - people often to hardcode it in the constructor, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4805094). but this was just a hunch.

Comment: @BagusTesa - while it's not exactly the same, it certainly helped me figure out the problem. I read `ConnectionString` in `MyContext.OnConfiguring()` from `appsettings.json` of the EF project when I do the migrations. But turns out it is also invoked when Web project is started, but it is using `appsettings.json` from the main project. That's why behavior was different, depending whether I put the value in main file, or in Development. Still need to figure out what is the right way - but at least I now know hot to get expected results. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Following @Bagus Tesa's hunch in the comment I started looking at the `MyContext` class. Here is the offending code:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    IConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");
    IConfiguration configuration = builder.Build();
    optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
}
```

This code is used during migration, using `appsettings.json` from `MyContext` project. However, it is **also** used when web application is running. Specifically, it is called during dependency injection in the controller. And since the connection string is in `appsettings.development.json` - this is *exactly* where `ConnectionString` is lost.

One way is to also use `appsettings.development.json` to match application project. However, it is obviously brittle - and for us wouldn't work, because we have numerous `appsettings.XXX.json` for various environments. Instead, it's better to check whether configuration was already loaded from application:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
   if (optionsBuilder.IsConfigured) return;
   ...
}
```

If it is documented anywhere - I couldn't find it. Hopefully, it will be useful for somebody else as well.